# Selenium - Writing to network drive. Can write a text file but not an image file

Tags: java, webdriver, javax.imageio, smb

I'm sorry if this was posted already but there seems to be so many answers so I thought I'd ask here to get some clarification. Im using the following screenshot Webdriver code to write a screenshot to my local drive, and works great:

```
final Screenshot screenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(
new ViewportPastingStrategy(500)).takeScreenshot(driver);
final BufferedImage image = screenshot.getImage();

File outputfile = new File("//Users/me/Desktop/testfolder/saved.png");
ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", outputfile);
```

This file write perfectly to my local drive. However, I want to write to a network drive that I have access to and have tested this access as I am able to write a text file.

The drive looks like this (with my name and password): smb://globalnerds;Carl.Lewis:Default32@file-16ca.bs.bview.com/bs-test/

I can write a text file there, but when I try to write the image it does not work.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Thanks!!

Comment: You should probably not post your real username/password, if you did, change it. :-) Other than that, did you write a text file from the Java program? Are you sure your Java program runs with the same access rights as your user?

Comment: thanks haraldK. this is not the real username or password. It's just for syntax. :) . I wrote a text file from the Java program YES. If I rename the file with .png, it will write too but will be an empty file.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out how to do this and worked like a charm using the below code. I grab an image and write it to a shared directory with credential. I'm passing my credentials and path in one line:

public void WriteMe() throws Exception {

```
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        //Get a picture
        File localFile = new File ("//Users/BIG.BEAR/Desktop/testfolder/saved.png");
        String remotePhotoUrl = "smb://globalnerds;BIG.BEAR:MYBEARPASSWORD@file-6666ca.haq.portview.com/testfolder/"; //The shared directory to store pictures
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS_");
        SmbFile remoteFile = new SmbFile (remotePhotoUrl + "/" + fmt.format (new Date ()) + localFile.getName ());
        remoteFile.connect (); //Try to connect

        in = new BufferedInputStream (new FileInputStream (localFile));
        out = new BufferedOutputStream (new SmbFileOutputStream (remoteFile));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int len = 0; //Read length
        while ((len = in.read (buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
            out.write (buffer, 0, len);
        }
        out.flush (); //The refresh buffer output stream
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String msg = "The error occurred: " + e.getLocalizedMessage ();
        System.out.println (msg);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close ();
            }
            if (in != null) {
                in.close ();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }


}
```